# Funciones Show y Hide no funcionan bien en Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

Estoy tratando de adaptar una pequeña app. web que usa algunas funciones jQuery y me he encontrado con que no oculta elementos de la página cuando con otro navegador si lo hace bien.

```
jQuery(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  jQuery('.dock').hide();  //esta linea no funciona
  jQuery('#menu a').on('click', function(e){    
    jQuery('.dock').hide();
    var target = jQuery(this.hash);
    console.log(target);
    jQuery(target).show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Algo del html:

```
<div id="docker" class="clearfix">
  <div id="enfermera" class="dock">
    <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="http://lauca3/certificasc"><img src="images/icons/icons8-Nurse_Female_100.png" alt="Panel" /><br/><span>Panel de enfermer&iacute;a</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="http://pabellones.alemana.cl/"><img src="images/icons/pabellon.jpg" alt="Pabell&oacute;n" /><span>Pabell&oacute;n</span></a>

    <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="file:///C:/cliexe/shc/Atn.exe"><img src="images/icons/fce.png" alt="F&iacute;cha Cl&iacute;nica" /><span><br/>F&iacute;cha Cl&iacute;nica</span></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Has probado a usar la función .ready() de JQuery?

Comment: Qué versión de IE usas?

Comment: Que version de JQuery usas y en que version de IE da problemas ?

Comment: Gracias amigo, no he usado eso de .ready. La verion de IE es la 9 y jquery es 2.2.2

Comment: @LuisF.Elgueta: La información relevante como la versión de IE y jQuery deberías agregarla a la pregunta ya que los comentarios son para uso provisional. En cuanto al uso de stack snippet, este sólo debe usarse cuando el código se pueda ejecutar en esta página. Por otro lado, deberías agregar un [mcve].

Comment: No debería ser un signo de # en vez de un punto? $("#dock").hide(); en vez de $(".dock").hide(); El signo de punto haces referencia a una clase de CSS y no a un elemento o tag de HTML

Answer (score 2):

Bendito IE y su incompatibilidad con todo mundo.

Primero intenta poniendole a la clase .doc una posición relativa en tu CSS

```
.dock{position: relative;}
```

Si no funciona intenta especificando la compatibilidad con IE 9 y 10

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,10;" />
```

Si no funciona cambiala por la compatibilidad con Edge

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

Ejemplo de como poner la compatibilidad

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,10;" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    ....
```

Más info [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)

Si nada de eso funciona tendrás que cambiar la versión de JQuery por la 1.9x o la 1.7x que es la que yo he usado para IE6 y me funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

Es un bug en IE. Puedes resolverlo utilizando algo de CSS. En vez de usar hide(), usa algo que dé el mismo efecto como un **display:none;**

```js
jQuery(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  
  jQuery('.dock').attr("style", "display: none;")   //esta linea ya debería funcionar
  jQuery('#menu a').on('click', function(e){ 
 
 var target = jQuery(this.hash);
 console.log(target);
 jQuery(target).show();
 e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="docker" class="clearfix">    
    <div id="enfermera" class="dock" >
     <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="http://lauca3/certificasc"><img src="images/icons/icons8-Nurse_Female_100.png" alt="Panel" /><br/><span>Panel de enfermer&iacute;a</span></a>
     <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="http://pabellones.alemana.cl/"><img src="images/icons/pabellon.jpg" alt="Pabell&oacute;n" /><span>Pabell&oacute;n</span></a> 
     
     <a target="_blank" class="dock-item" href="file:///C:/cliexe/shc/Atn.exe"><img src="images/icons/fce.png" alt="F&iacute;cha Cl&iacute;nica" /><span><br/>F&iacute;cha Cl&iacute;nica</span></a> 
      
    </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Estimado amigo user2930137, lo probe pero no funcinó  :( Simplemente sigue mostrando todo lo que deberia estar oculto, que desgracia es trabajar con este navegador !! xD

Comment: Lo sé, yo trabajé con el IE8 y está peor. Pero vamos, esto se tiene que resolver. Dime, te marca algún error en al consola del IE?

Comment: Para las etiquetas <option>, Lixus

Comment: La verdad es que no, salen unos errores que son de CSS que no se muy bien de que tratan. Pero no parece tener relacion con eñ script....

Comment: Los errores de css no aparecen en al consola... creo XD el display none debería funcionar, creo que el que no funciona es el attr. Intenta con .css("display", "none"); a ver xdd

Comment: Gracias :) .....

Comment: Funcionó? .......

Comment: NO  :/ .........

Comment: >:c Sube en una imagen lo que te sale en la consola, porfa

Answer (score 1):

Puede que sea debido a conflicto con otras bibliotecas. Intenta usando:

```
$('.dock').hide();
```

en vez de:

```
jQuery('.dock').hide();
```

También comprueba que no tengas algún caracter de más en todo tu javascript, que tengas bien declarado el `$(document).ready(function(){}`, etc. IE se fija en todo.

Comment: Gracias Adriana, de momento sigo en el mismo lugar :(

Comment: Bueno, siento no haber podido ayudarte, IE siempre dando conflictos. Quizas si pones todo tu código javascript alguien se de cuenta donde pudiera haber algo que no le guste a IE y esté causandote el conflicto y por ahi se arregle. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Adriana. un abrazo.